# Having issues with basic responsive functionality

Tags: html, css, responsive

Want to float a YT video over an image, and have everything be responsive.

1. I do need the YT video to start at a particular size, and then be responsive with the image it is on top of

Here is what I currently have, I need to fix a couple of things:

1. Ensure the YT video starts at a certain size within the image (attached example)
2. Everything shrinks if screen gets smaller

Example Image
[image]

Current  Code:

```css
.container {
       border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
       position: relative;
    
    }
    .tag {
       float: left;
       position: absolute;
       left: 3%;
       top: 14%;
       z-index: 1000;
       background-color: #000000;
       padding: 5px;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size:8vw
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tag"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aaYqazlUMOA?controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/732x295" alt="poulin" class="responsive">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, since you know the height and the width of the image bellow (732x295), why you don't set the iframe width and height to a value bellow that, ex: (560x220)?

Comment: So the image works fine, it actually is responsive, my bigger concern is making the YT video responsive WITH the image, because on smaller screens, the YT video is bigger than the image